# Flutter upgrade error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten

Tags: flutter, upgrade

Upgrading the Flutter SDK and packages

```
    My-Mac:~ admin$ flutter upgrade

    Upgrading Flutter from /Users/admin/Desktop/SDK/flutter...
    error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        packages/flutter/lib/src/services/message_codecs.dart
    Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
    Aborting
    Updating 2eeeXXXe9..7XXXbf4aX
```

I have gone on the flutter SDK and check `status` and got below things

```
My-Mac:flutter admin$  git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 565 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   dev/automated_tests/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/benchmarks/macrobenchmarks/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/bots/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/devicelab/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/integration_tests/android_views/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/integration_tests/channels/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/integration_tests/external_ui/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/integration_tests/flavors/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/integration_tests/platform_interaction/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/integration_tests/ui/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/manual_tests/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/snippets/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/tools/pubspec.yaml
modified:   dev/tools/vitool/pubspec.yaml
modified:   examples/catalog/pubspec.yaml
modified:   examples/flutter_gallery/pubspec.yaml
modified:   examples/hello_world/pubspec.yaml
modified:   examples/layers/pubspec.yaml
modified:   examples/platform_channel/pubspec.yaml
modified:   examples/platform_channel_swift/pubspec.yaml
modified:   examples/stocks/pubspec.yaml
modified:   packages/flutter/lib/src/services/message_codecs.dart
modified:   packages/flutter/pubspec.yaml
modified:   packages/flutter_driver/pubspec.yaml
modified:   packages/flutter_goldens/pubspec.yaml
modified:   packages/flutter_localizations/pubspec.yaml
modified:   packages/flutter_test/pubspec.yaml
modified:   packages/flutter_tools/pubspec.yaml
modified:   packages/fuchsia_remote_debug_protocol/pubspec.yaml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    OLDSDK.zip

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

After do above task now try to upgrade again Flutter but got again error mentioned below

```
My-Mac:flutter admin$ flutter upgrade
    Building flutter tool...
    Because flutter_tools depends on sockjs_client 0.3.5 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
    Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
    .
    .
    Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (1 tries left)
    Command 'pub upgrade' still failed after 10 tries, giving up.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter uses git for SDK management.
You'd need to review your repository located in $HOME/development/flutter.
You can use git command to check your repostory status.
For example,

```
$ git status
```

To see your local change

```
$ git branch
```

To see which branch you are using.

Following steps might help you when you find you've changed something uncommitted, but you would like to undo all changed to simply switch to latest version (master).

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

To undo all your changes.

```
$ git checkout master
```

To switch to master branch

```
$ git pull
```

To pull down and sync all commit on server.

Answer (score 1):

You have some uncomitted changes in the flutter SDK, If You want to remove those changes and upgrade flutter, then you can force upgrade

`flutter upgrade -f`

> Force upgrade the flutter branch, potentially discarding local changes.

Comment: This only works if there is a new version. If you are on the latest version this does not do anything,.

Comment: This ended up working for me

Comment: @under when you are already on the latest version what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe accidentally edit flutter code.

To fix it, go to your flutter folder, it should be /Users/admin/Desktop/SDK/flutter

and check any changes by run

```
git status
```

If anything changes, in your case you made change packages/flutter/lib/src/services/message_codecs.dart, just revert it by :

```
git checkout -- packages/flutter/lib/src/services/message_codecs.dart
```